# Can I free the concentration camp prisoners in chapter 3?

Tags: metro-last-light

While making your way through the Reich's concentration camp, the prisoners keep asking you to open the cells door from the guard room (or however they translated it in the English version) and mention that it is somewhere above. I haven't figured out a way to reach it and had to ride the elevator out of that area. Was it possible for me to free them and if so, would doing so have any consequences down the road?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out the elevator is how you reach the guard rooms where the cages' controls are. The controls are in the well-lit room overlooking the cages, take 2 right turns to reach it after leaving the elevator.